# How to maintain array value in localstorge even if page is refreshed in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage

**HelloWorld.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.cakeid">
      <b> id: {{ item.cakeid }}</b>
      <router-link
        :to="{
          name: 'UserWithID',
          params: { id: item.cakeid },
          query: { cakeid: item.cakeid },
        }"
      >
        {{ item.cakeName }}
      </router-link>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <User />
    <br /><br /><br />
    <tabs />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import User from "./User.vue";
import tabs from "./tabs.vue";
import { router } from "./router";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {
    User,
    tabs,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: router,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**User.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, key) in user" :key="key">
      {{ item.cakeName }} <br />
      {{ user.total }}{{ item.cakePrice }} <br />
      {{ user.total }}{{ item.total }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { routerid } from "./routerid";
export default {
  name: "User",
  data() {
    return {
      lists: routerid,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    user: function () {
      return this.lists.filter((item) => {
        if (item.cakeid === this.$route.params.id) {
          return item;
        }
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**tabs.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, key) in user" :key="key">
      {{ item.chefname }} <br />
      {{ user.feedback }}{{ item.rating }} <br />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { tabsandcontent } from "./tabsandcontent";
export default {
  name: "User",
  data() {
    return {
      lists: tabsandcontent,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    user: function () {
      return this.lists.filter((item) => {
        if (item.cakeid === this.$route.params.id) {
          return item;
        }
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

How to keep data alive, Even after page is refreshed in Vuejs?

On clicking of routerlink, I am filtering  some values  based on each array id. and displaying those array values.

During this process,  after array values are displayed on click of router-link, if i refresh the page, All the array values which is displayed previously is not getting displayed.

I want to keep data, as it is(like previously clicked to state) even after page is refreshed. I think this can be handled by using the localstorage get and set items.

But not sure where to place it.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you refresh the page, this part `this.$route.params.id` in `User.vue` returns the id as a string and you are checking `item.cakeid === this.$route.params.id` using three equal symbols.
Thus meaning that not only you require the values to be equal but also to be the same type.

Just change that to `==` or use the `parseInt` function to parse the integer from the string.